# What is the probability of two rolling dice?

Tags: probability

I have an interview tomorrow and I need the answer to this question. Math is rusty. Can you help?

What is the probability the same number appears in both of them when a 4 faced die and 6 faced die are rolled?

Comment: It depends.  What numbers are on the 4-faced die and on the 6-faced die?

Comment: Are you assuming that the dice are fair?

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as the question in the text. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roll the four-faced die and get one of four numbers.  Assuming those four are among $1,2,3,4,5,6$ (for example, they could be $1,2,3,4$), then when you roll a standard six-faced die, the probability of getting that same number is $1/6$.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this by counting. Assuming canonical dice i.e. faces numbered 1 through $n$, $n$ = 4, 6 then of the 6$\times$4 = 24 different possible throws, 4 of them have the same number on each die for probability $\frac{1}{6}$.